# What are the possible values of $P\cdot Q$

Tags: logic

If $P$ and $Q$ are integers such that $Q>P$ and $PQ-P-Q=90$.

What I got is that:
-the last digit of $P+Q$ should be equal to the last digit of $PQ$
-From guessing, I got $PQ=0$ for $P=-90$ and $Q=0$

How should I approach this type of problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should write the LHS as $(P-1)(Q-1)-1$.

Answer (score 0):

One way to solve these kinds of equations is to check every case.

Rearranging the equation and writing it as $(P-1)(Q-1)=91=13\times7$.

Possible outcomes for $(P-1)$ and $(Q-1)$ for which $Q\gt P$ are

- 1 $\,$ $\,$ and $\,$ 91  gives $\,$ $P=0$ ,$\,$ $Q=92$ $\,$ $\,$ and $\,$ $P.Q=0$
- 7 $\,$$\,$ and $\,$ 13  gives $\,$ $P=8$ ,$\,$ $Q=14$ $\,$ $\,$ and $\,$ $P.Q=112$
- -13 and -7  gives $\,$ $P=-12$ ,$\,$ $Q=-6$ $\,$ and $\,$ $P.Q=72$

So Possible outcomes for $P.Q$ are $0$ , $112$ and $72$.